# Acer Aspire 4710: Additional Drivers in Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, kubuntu

After a clean install of Kubuntu 13.04 i386 on an Acer Aspire 4710, the Broadcom BCM4311 wireless adapter worked, but would disconnect from time to time, and not reconnect reliably.

The "Additional Drivers" application showed that proprietary drivers were available. After installing these and restarting, no wireless connection was available and the "Additional Drivers" application was empty -- it reports no proprietary drivers are available and none are in use on the computer.

I connected via Ethernet and did a full system update, restarted, and ran "Additional Drivers" again, but it is still empty and I still have no wireless connection available.

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Additional Drivers' installs the wrong driver for the 4311 device. Please get a temporary ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```

Any improvement? It may take a reboot.